# Command Object in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and not sure how to proceed on my requirement.

**My Requirement is as follows:**

I have created web application using spring and tiles.

I need to pass the xml to the web app, I tried it by sending the xml in url.

```
Example: 
http://domain-name/SpringExample/welcome.htm?requestXml=”my xml string………..
```

But the problem is the xml is very large, hence the application is not accepting the complete string.

Hence, My plan is to use command object (declaring a variable in command object and then using this variable to get this xml in the jsp page)
But I am not sure how to use it, I googled but could only find that the command object is created and populated in the web app itself, i.e. created in one page and send to other.

But for me I need to send it from external client. From the client, i need to send this large xml request to my spring web application using command object.
I am not sure of how to invoke this from client, also how to read this in web application.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance 

**Details:**

I have single spring tiles web application. My client is a simple java application which will invoke this spring application and send xml string to it
I read somewhere that in such scenarios, i need to use command object to pass my data to the web app.

Spring Web application

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome.htm")
@SessionAttributes("requestObj")
public class WelcomeController {  

@RequestMapping(value="requestObj", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect(@RequestParam("requestObj") SampleClass requestObj, ModelMap model)
{       
    Model.addAttribute("reqXml", requestObj.getXmlString());      
    return "welcome";    //returns to the jsp page
 }
```

Client:

```
 String url = "http://localhost/SpringTilesWebApp/welcome.htm";
 String finalURL = url + "?" + "requestObj=" + requestObj;
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec  
("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + finalURL);
```

I am really not sure if I am going in the right direction or not, please suggest me the way..

Comment: The problem occurs most likely earlier, since you send the whole XML document as part of the URL. Try to use a POST request instead and send the document in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks Henry!! Can you please post some sample code, it could be really helpful. Also, can we do this using command object?

Comment: See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339137/xml-json-post-with-requestbody-in-spring-rest-controller

Comment: Henry please check the details added above,as per requirement i need to use command object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use post request to the server-side app. You can use apache httpclient tool for that. Eg:

```
String url = "http://localhost/SpringTilesWebApp/welcome.htm";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestObj", requestObj));    

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    //read and process response
```

On the spring mvc side you can annotate your controller method with

```
       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String redirect(@RequestParam("requestObj") SampleClass requestObj, 
                                                                  ModelMap model)
```

and you can use now the requestObj.

The command object you are talking about, what is it? Are you talking about the command design pattern or is related to a technology/fw you are using?

Comment: Thanxs Alex for the answer :)

Comment: I had one more doubt.....when I invoke the spring web app from client, it is working with POST, but when i deploy and run the standalone web app, it doesnt work (I mean it says page not found)....On the other hand, the standalone web app runs when the controller request mapping is GET...I am not able to understand why there is the diff and also is there anything more i need to do, to make both (standalone app and invoked from client) work?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you even try to send it by GET? As the name says, the HTTP GET method must be used when trying to GET a resource.

You must send the xml document using the POST method (or PUT). You can put it as a hidden input field for example.

Can you detail a little more please? 
Who is the client(s)? It's only one spring mvc app or there are decoupled (backend from the frontend client)?

Comment: Hi Alex, Added some details, please check